# Should I use a contingency table or Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test? (is chi squared nonparametric)

Tags: chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, nonparametric

I have a debate over whether a contingency table or Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test (WRST) should be used in a particular situation.  There are several problems with the contingency table, but I will mention one at the end having to do with whether the chi squared test is parametric or nonparametric that I am especially interested in resolving.  I favor the WRST, but I am open to arguments in favor of the contingency table.

In this situation, N numbers were generated by process 1 and M numbers were generated by process 2, where N > M.  The numbers are between 0 and 1. (Or they are percents.)  I want to know which process tends to produce bigger numbers.  In fact, process 1 basically always produces bigger numbers than process 2, but I want to know if N and M are large enough that this difference is statistically significant.   (Actually, N = 8 and M = 6.)  I know of no way to find out the probability distribution of process 1 or process 2, so it seems to me that a nonparametric test is called for.  I want to use the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test.

However, another person wants me to use a contingency table.  They say that WRST is only useful when process 1 and process 2 are known to have the same distribution, differing only by a shift.  This seems untrue, according to Wikipedia's entry on the Mann-Whitney U test, another name for the WRST (see #4 under "assumptions and formal statement of hypotheses" which clearly does not assume the distributions differ only by a shift.)

At any rate, the contingency table seems potentially wrong just because if N > M, it is unclear what the size of the table would be.  (2 x M or 2 x N?)  However, say for the sake of argument that I could coerce the data into a table, maybe by throwing out data from process 1 until they are equal in size or by grouping the data into bins and averaging them.  (There are problems with either approach, but bear with me.)  There is still a problem in that the data are most naturally expressed as numbers between 0 and 1, but the contingency table I think expects integers as input.  Still, for the sake of argument let's say I somehow deal with that problem too.  There remains a huge problem (in my opinion) in that I think the chi squared test is parametric.  (I think contingency tables are often based on chi squared?)  I believe it assumes that the integers in the table are generated by a Poisson or multinomial process; but I don't know if process 1 and process 2 are Poisson or multinomial; they almost certainly are not - there is no reason for them to be.

Here is the crux of the problem: the thing that is causing arguments is that some sources say chi square is nonparametric:

http://benbaab.com/salkind/ChiSquare.html

While other sources say a contingency table assumes its cells are Poisson:

http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c5.pdf (see page 5)

Can anyone tell me whether I should use a contingency table or Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test - and how I can resolve this contradiction between the two websites quoted above in such a way as to prove who is right (both to myself and to the other person)?  Are the websites somehow both right?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: 1. Are these values between 0 and 1 discrete (e.g. a count divided by a total count) or continuous (each number could be any value in [0,1] at all, rather than an individual number only being able to take a limited number of distinct values)? 2. "Nonparametric" has a couple of (related) meanings (about the number of parameters needed to specify one or another thing) and in addition, some books use it to mean "distribution-free", which is not quite the same thing, but is somewhat related to one of the meanings. (Lastly, and quite wrongly, some people use it to mean anything non-normal.) ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  What are you actually after when you ask about a nonparametric procedure, and why do you want one?

Comment: 3. When you say " In fact, process 1 basically always produces bigger numbers than process 2" do you simply mean "all 6 values from process 1 were bigger than all 8 from process 2" or something else? 4. The signed rank test is for paired data. If you have 6 and 8 observations, what's paired with what? 5. Note that there's never really any way to find out the functional form of a distribution from data; people make simple assumptions which are often vaguely plausible from external considerations and which don't seem so badly wrong they'll give misleading conclusions.

Comment: 6. How is your colleague going to be calculating a chi-square on numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: @Jvonkof You may try test of difference between proportions for process 1 and Process 2.

Comment: @Glen_b, 

1. the values between 0 and 1 are sort of discrete (a count divided by a total count) but the total count may be different for different values.  So one may be 2/28 and another 7/40.

2. I want a nonparametric procedure because I don't know the probability distribution of process 1 or process 2.  So it could be that the numbers have a uniform distribution between 0 and 1, or they could be approximately normal, or (more likely) they could be some crazy other distribution that I can't predict.

Comment: 3. There was one of the 8 values from process 1 that was smaller than one of the 6 values from process 2.  Other than that, all values from process 1 were bigger.  However, I tested another feature of the system (there are multiple qualitatively different features) and in that trial, all of the 8 values were _smaller_ than all of the 6 values.  So in a sense the answer to your question is "both."  Both behaviors are relevant.

4. I think the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test is for paired data, but the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test is not.

Comment: 5. That's true.  It is hard for me to figure out a plausible distribution a priori, but I could get it by staring at the data for instance?

6. That is what I don't understand either.  I guess I had no experience with contingency tables, so I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious.  Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: @subhash c. davar, I am not familiar with the test of difference between proportions, but it looks like this requires data in the form of integers that are counting something.

Comment: Isn't that what you have? If you have counts divided by total counts then unless you don't have the totals they were divided by you have exactly what's needed for a test of proportions.

Comment: Good point.  Can it handle fourteen proportions all at once (6 vs. 8) or only one proportion vs. one proportion at a time?  This seems to do a comparison of one vs. one: http://stattrek.com/sampling/difference-in-proportion.aspx